# LetsEncrypt certificate (renewing) installing error

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache2, lets-encrypt, ssl-certificate-errors, ssl-certificate-renewal

I'm trying to renew my LetsEncrypt certificate on my Raspberry Pi running apache2, but I seem to get an error when CertBot tries to generate the certificate.

```
Expected sha256 a988718abfad80b6b157acce7bf130a30876d27603738ac39f140993246b25b3
         Got        6162f1c328e42d9bd4e74ca234a575748f199e40f56d5ec3204d55cd130cfd7e
```

I've tried manually running it by updating my DNS records on my domain but I seem to get this error

```
    Failed authorization procedure. theflyingrat.com (dns-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.theflyingrat.com

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: mydomain.com
   Type:   None
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for
   _acme-challenge.mydomain.com
```

If I can, I want to be able to know how to install a Wildcard certificate, but that also gives me errors. I've tried the --certonly parameter on a Raspberry Pi Zero to hopefully give me the certificate there so I can migrate it over to my main Pi Server, but that (as you guessed) also gives me the SAME errors.

Thanks in advance, P.s, the (non-wildcard) certificate expired yesterday, so a fast response would be very grateful.

Thanks, Rat

Comment: "NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.theflyingrat.com"  means that you did not publish the TXT record in the DNS as certbot asked you to do. Until you do that, no certificate renewal will be possible.

Comment: "certificate expired yesterday"  and why did you wait? there is no sense waiting for the last time, you should start renewing your certificates automatically 30 days before expiration.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I've added the TXT record, but still after 10 minutes, it still produces that error.

Comment: just advice, I think it's better to create new certificate then renew if it has a problem.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur how it is better? The validation process is exactly the same in both cases...

Comment: "I've added the TXT record", no because even the authoritative nameservers on your zone do not publish it. So the record has not been added to the zone; Consult your DNS provider help/support to understand why.

Comment: you can choose another validation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem got fixed because I ran this command:

```
sudo certbot certonly --webroot
```

turns out I needed the --webroot parameter.

Sorry about the trouble,

-Rat (Joey)